# Series describe function pandas ploting

Tags: python, pandas, plot, statistics, dataset

I have question for you. Which plot is a best to show describe result in series pandas

```
filter = genderage['Customer_Gender'] == "F"
genderage[filter]
genderage[filter].describe()

    Customer_Age
count   54724.000000
mean    36.168993
std 10.910622
min 17.000000
25% 28.000000
50% 35.000000
75% 43.000000
max 87.000000
```

Answer (score 7, accepted):

A `boxplot` will combine nearly all of this information into a single visualization. It won't plot the `mean` by default but you can add that as a dashed line with `meanline` and `showmeans`.

The whiskers extrend from the `max` to the `min`. The dashed line is the mean. The box extends from the 25% to 75% and the solid line in the box is the median (50%). You just miss the standard deviation and the counts, which can be added as text if you wanted.

```
import numpy as np
import pandas as pd

np.random.seed(123)
s = pd.Series(np.random.chisquare(34, 100))

s.describe()
#count    100.000000
#mean      34.674010
#std        8.393988
#min       15.306646
#25%       29.043357
#50%       33.556184
#75%       40.380201
#max       56.930963
#dtype: float64

s.to_frame('data').boxplot(meanline=True, showmeans=True)
```

[image]